# How can I mount a water heater element to a GoldenGate keg?

Tags: electric, boil-kettle

I have what I think is a GoldenGate style keg. It's got a bunghole, a tapped hole on top and another near the base.

I want to mount a electric hot water heater element in the base hole.

The base hole is 1.5" in diameter and the thread is 2" and ~.07" between threads.

Optimally, I'd get a reducer bushing, but I can't even find a thread size that matches these dimensions.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to make that adapter yourself. Water heater threads are usually NPS or standard threads where your SS fittings are NPT Pipe threads. Your best bet is to weld the correct bung or adapter into the keg side.

I have seen 120V 1400+W immersion heaters that use o-ring style seals but will not heat as well as 220v elements.

Another choice that I have seen in practice is an Instant Hot water heater like you would see under a kitchen sink. They easily hit Mash temps and can fill 10 gals. Just an idea.

Hope that helps,
Pat

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest thing is to cut a hole in the side of the keg and install the heater there. Then fasten it so there is no leak.